# Find duplicate records based on multiple columns but where one of the columns is a duplicate but a different column is not

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a log table named FileLog. Here's a sample of how that log table would look like:

| LogFileName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename1.xml | Null |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename1.xml | Error |
| Filename1.xml | SomeOtherStatus |
| Filename1.xml | Null |

| LogFileName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename1.xml | Null |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename2.xml | Error |
| Filename3.xml | SomeOtherStatus |
| Filename2.xml | Null |
| Filename3.xml | OK |
| Filename4.xml | Null |
| Filename4.xml | OK |
| Filename5.xml | Null |
| Filename5.xml | OK |
| Filename5.xml | OK |

| LogFileName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename1.xml | OK |

| LogFileName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename1.xml | Null |

The above would be considered a duplicate. Valid combinations of the Status field must have at least 2 records of the following combination to be considered a duplicate (along with the same LogFileName):

- OK/OK
- OK/NULL

Below would not be considered a duplicate:

| LogFileName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | OK |
| Filename1.xml | Error |
| Filename1.xml | SomeOtherStatus |

| LogFileName | Status |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | Null |
| Filename1.xml | Null |

I've attempted to write a simple query but it is not returning the expected results:

```
select 
LogFileName
,status
,count(LogFileName)
from FileLog fl
where statustext is null or statustext = 'ok' group by LogFileNamehaving count(info)>1
```

Here is my expected result/outcome based on the examples given abovefor valid duplicates:

| LogFileName | Duplicate Count |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | 6 |

| LogFileName | Duplicate Count |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | 3 |
| Filename4.xml | 2 |
| Filename5.xml | 3 |

| LogFileName | Duplicate Count |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | 2 |

| LogFileName | Duplicate Count |
| --- | --- |
| Filename1.xml | 2 |

Can anyone help me with pointers on how to write the query to return the duplicates based on the criteria above?

Comment: Show us one sample data, and its expected result. Use filename2, filename3 etc to give duplicates etc.

Comment: @jarlh - sorry about that, added!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can use conditional aggregation for this.

Essentially your conditions are either:

- Two `OK` values.
- Or at least one `OK` value and one `NULL` value.

```sql
SELECT
  fl.LogFileName,
  COUNT(*) AS Duplicates
FROM FileLog fl
GROUP BY
  fL.LogFileName
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN fl.Status = 'OK' THEN 1 END) >= 2
    OR (
       COUNT(CASE WHEN fl.Status = 'OK' THEN 1 END) = 1
       AND
       COUNT(CASE WHEN fl.Status IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 0
    );
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/hAl6EAuI)

Counting nulls can also be done like this `COUNT(*) - COUNT(fl.Status)`.

Comment: This is great. Thank you. This works for me. I've learned something new, thank you for the knowledge

Answer (score 1):

This is based on the sample data in your second table but I added a few more records to test the OK/OK scenario. I've not tested it against the others but it should be OK.

Not the most elegant solution in the world but it works.

I wasn't sure is `NULL` was an actual `NULL` or a string `"NULL"` so this answer handles both.

```
-- recreate the sample data
CREATE TABLE FileLog(LogFileName varchar(50), Status varchar(50));
INSERT INTO FileLog Values
('Filename1.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename1.xml', 'Null'),
('Filename1.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename2.xml', 'Error'),
('Filename3.xml', 'SomeOtherStatus'),
('Filename2.xml', 'Null'),
('Filename3.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename4.xml', 'Null'),
('Filename4.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename5.xml', Null),
('Filename5.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename5.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename6.xml', 'OK'),
('Filename6.xml', 'OK');

-- create 4 CTE's 
-- 1. one has file log entry counts which is what we need to finally return
-- 2. a list of filenames with at least one OK
-- 3. a list of filenames with at at lkeast 2 OKs
-- 4. a list of filenames with at least one NULL
WITH 
  FileCounts AS (SELECT LogFileName, rCount = COUNT(*) FROM FileLog GROUP BY LogFileName)
, HasOK AS (SELECT DISTINCT LogFileName FROM FileLog WHERE Status = 'OK')
, HasMultipleOK AS (SELECT LogFileName FROM FileLog WHERE Status = 'OK' GROUP BY LogFileName HAVING COUNT(*)>1)
, HasNull AS (SELECT DISTINCT LogFileName FROM FileLog WHERE ISNULL(Status, 'NULL') = 'NULL')

-- select anything where we have 2 or more OKs or an OK and a NULL
SELECT 
    fc.* 
    FROM FileCounts fc 
        LEFT JOIN HasOK o on fc.LogFileName  = o.LogFileName
        LEFT JOIN HasMultipleOK o2 on fc.LogFileName  = o2.LogFileName
        LEFT JOIN HasNull n on fc.LogFileName  = n.LogFileName
    WHERE (o2.LogFileName IS NOT NULL)
        OR (o.LogFileName IS NOT NULL AND n.LogFileName IS NOT NULL)
```

Here's a dbfiddle with it in action

https://dbfiddle.uk/RlHIZFrV

Comment: I think you can do this with just one level of aggregation.

Comment: As I said *"Not the most elegant solution in the world but it works."* :) . To be fair it was almost midnight when I wrote it but your answer is much better.

Comment: Thank you @AlanSchofield for burning the midnight oil on this. To answer your question it is an actual NULL. This solution does work for me